# How to auto fill the shipping address field

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.1

I'm a beginner magento 2 user. Now, I want to set some default value in the shipping address's field, could you teach me what should I do? What file should I need to code?

Thank very much.

The below image is my expect result:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In that case you need a plugin for this.

Create di.xml [Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="vendor_assign_default_value" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create LayoutProcessor.php [Vendor/Module/Plugin/Checkout/Model/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php]

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout;


class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['firstname']['value'] = 'FirstName';

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['company']['value'] = 'Demo Company';
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: This used to work, but now it does not. The First Name field has an error message though: `This is a required field.`

Comment: Hi Sohel, it works fine. But it's not working for email field. is there any solution for that?

Comment: It is not working in Magento 2.2 throws an error This is required field

Comment: @StevieG & Moin Malek Were you guys able to find the solution for "This is a required Field error." ?

Comment: @SohelRana... I am using your SR/ModifiedChekout module..in that i wish to auto fill the billing address fields with default billing address for the logged in customer... How to do that ..Kindly help me

Comment: please help me to set the value for input field region(not region_id). i tried a lot. couldnt find solution...