# How to prefill Magento2 checkout email field?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, magento-2.0.7

I am passing email from some other page which I want to auto fill in check out page shipping address form. I have been referring to [How to auto fill the shipping address field](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141505/how-to-auto-fill-the-shipping-address-field)

it works for other fields but not working for email. Please help.

Comment: have you found solution ?

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution? If yes, can you share?