# How to auto fill the shipping address field in Checkout in Magento 2.2

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.2, shipping-address

I had referred this link [How to auto fill the shipping address field](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141505/how-to-auto-fill-the-shipping-address-field) but this is throw an error This is required Field.

I have to Auto fill Address in Magento 2 Checkout. I have to fill the State and Zip code.

Can anyone have idea to fill it?

```
di.xml file in `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend`




<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="vendor_assign_default_value" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
```

LayoutProcessor file in  Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor as MageLayoutProcessor;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    public function afterProcess(MageLayoutProcessor $subject, $jsLayout)
    {

        $jsLayout['components']['

checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['postcode']['value'] = '10012';



         return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: Specify what code you have try?

Comment: Hello @DhirenVasoya please check edited question

Comment: Also specify the code which you have done in di.xml and also specify the location of di.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your `di.xml` file from :

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml
```

To

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml
```

With code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="vendor_assign_default_value" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: This is not working on Magento 2.2.x. It's giving error "This is a required field". Do you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: after implementing this, run deploy command and caching command. Then check.

Comment: It just started working suddenly. No idea, why. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, I followed the code which you suggested but it's not working. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304907/magento2-3-2-how-to-autofill-the-shipping-address-at-checkout-page