# How to auto fill (add default value) the shipping address in Magento 2.3

Tags: shipping-address, magento2.3, checkout-page

I want to auto fill the field (such as First Name, Street Address, State/Province..) in Shipping address (checkout page).

like this : 
[image]

I have reference some solution such as :
[How to auto fill the shipping address field](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141505/how-to-auto-fill-the-shipping-address-field) or [How to auto fill the shipping address field in Checkout in Magento 2.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202675/how-to-auto-fill-the-shipping-address-field-in-checkout-in-magento-2-2)

But I can match the file path of the above solution . I think it is not match the Magento 2.3 version.I want to know the detail step to set the default value in the field in Shipping address page.

Please help me.......